# How do I find all subsets of an array that sum to zero using recursion? (In Ruby)

Tags: ruby, recursion, subset-sum

I'm new to coding and new to Ruby. I'm working on this problem in my spare time since I am new to ruby and am having a difficult time getting my code to iterate through every created subset.

Here is my code:

```
#Given a set of integers, and a value sum, i.e. value sum of 0
#determine if there is a subset of the given set with sum equal to given sum.

class Array
    def SubSetSumtoZero
        if self.collect{|sum,x| sum + x  == 0}
            detected = self.select {|sum,x| sum + x == 0}
            puts "\r\n #{detected} Sums to Zero \r\n"
        else self.collect{|sum,x| sum + x  -= 0}
            notdetected = self.select {|sum, x| sum + x -= 0}
            puts "\r\n#{notdetected} Does not sum to Zero\r\n"
        end
    end
end

originalSet = [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]
arr = []

for i in 2..(originalSet.length) do
    arr = arr + originalSet.combination(i).to_a
    arr.SubSetSumtoZero
end
```

And here are my results:

```
[[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2]] Sums to Zero 

 [[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2], [-7, 7, 9], [-2, 2, 7], [-2, 2, 9]] Sums to Zero 

 [[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2], [-7, 7, 9], [-2, 2, 7], [-2, 2, 9], [-2, 2, 7, 9]] Sums to Zero 

 [[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2], [-7, 7, 9], [-2, 2, 7], [-2, 2, 9], [-2, 2, 7, 9]] Sums to Zero 

 [[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2], [-7, 7, 9], [-2, 2, 7], [-2, 2, 9], [-2, 2, 7, 9]] Sums to Zero 
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I know that at some point the entire array will sum up to zero. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are those `-=` supposed to be `!=`?

Comment: I just changed my code to reflect and != and it didn't error out, but doesn't make a difference in the output. I initially tried using != and got an error and found out that -= seems to serve the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward recursive solution would be to write a function that computes the powerset of an array. Afterwards, select all elements in the powerset that fulfills your desired predicate.

An example implementation:

```
def powerset(array)
  if array.empty?
    [[]]
  else
    first_elem, *rest_elems = array
    subsets = []
    powerset(rest_elems).each do |subset|
      subsets.push(subset)
      subsets.push(subset.clone.push(first_elem))
    end
    subsets
  end
end

def sums_to_zero?(array)
  array.reduce(0, :+) == 0
end

def subsets_that_sum_to_zero(array)
  powerset(array).select { |subset| sums_to_zero?(subset) }
end

original_set = [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]
subsets_that_sum_to_zero(original_set).each do |subset|
  puts "The subset #{subset} sums to zero!"
end

# The subset [] sums to zero!
# The subset [2, -2] sums to zero!
# The subset [7, -7] sums to zero!
# The subset [7, 2, -9] sums to zero!
# The subset [7, 2, -2, -7] sums to zero!
# The subset [9, -9] sums to zero!
# The subset [9, -2, -7] sums to zero!
# The subset [9, 2, -2, -9] sums to zero!
# The subset [9, 7, -7, -9] sums to zero!
# The subset [9, 7, 2, -2, -7, -9] sums to zero!
```

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) for an explanation of the powerset algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I know you specifically asked for a recursive solution, but since @hjing has provided one, I would like to show you how your question can be answered in a more compact and straightforward way by using powerful, built-in methods from Ruby's `Enumerable` module and `Array` class.

**Code**

```
def find_it(array, tot)
  (1..array.size).each_with_object([]) { |n,arr|
    array.combination(n).each { |a| arr << a if a.reduce(:+) == tot } }
end
```

**Example**

```
find_it([-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9], 0) #=> [-9, 9]
  #=> [[-9, 9], [-7, 7], [-2, 2],
  #    [-9, 2, 7], [-7, -2, 9],
  #    [-9, -7, 7, 9], [-9, -2, 2, 9], [-7, -2, 2, 7],
  #    [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]]
```

**Explanation**

```
array = [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]
tot   = 0

r = 1..array.size             #=> 1..6 (Range object)
```

Each value of this range is size of subsets that will be considered.  We will first examine subsets of size 1, then subsets of size 2, and so on, up to subsets of size 6, of which there is but one (`array`).

```
enum1 = r.each_with_object([]) # => #<Enumerator: 1..6:each_with_object([])>
```

To see the values that the enumerator `enum1` will pass to its block, we can convert it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a  #=> [[1, []], [2, []], [3, []], [4, []], [5, []], [6, []]]
```

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) creates an initially empty array that is represented by the block variable `arr`.  That first value `enum` passes to its block is the array `[0, []]`, causing the block variables to be assigned as follows:

```
n   => 1
arr => []

enum2 = array.combination(n) #=> array.combination(1)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]:combination(1)>
```

Here [Array#combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) generates all combinations of one element from `array`. `enum2` will therefore pass the following elements to its block:

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[-9], [-7], [-2], [2], [7], [9]]
```

The first element `enum2` passes to its block is `[-9]`, causing the bloc block variable to be assigned as follows:

```
a => [-9]
```

so the block expression becomes:

```
arr << a if a.reduce(:+) == tot #=> arr << [-9] if [-9].reduce(:+) == 0
```

[Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka, `inject`) with argument `:+` (the addition method) merely sums the elements of its receiver, `[-9]`, which obviously is `-9`.  As `-9 != 0`, `[-9]` is not appended to `arr`.  Clearly, the only array containing a single element that sums to zero is `[0]`, but that array is not present in this example.  Therefore, `arr` remains empty after `enum2` has enumerated all its elements.

`enum1` now passes the element `[2, []]` to its block, setting the block variables to:

```
n   => 2
arr => []
```

resulting in:

```
enum2 = array.combination(n) #=> array.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [-9, -7, -2, 2, 7, 9]:combination(2)>
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[-9, -7], [-9, -2], [-9, 2], [-9, 7], [-9, 9], [-7, -2], [-7, 2],
  #    [-7,  7], [-7,  9], [-2, 2], [-2, 7], [-2, 9], [ 2,  7], [ 2, 9], [7, 9]]
```

We find that elements `[-9, 9]`, `[-7, 7]` and `[-2, 2]` each sum to zero, so `arr` becomes:

```
arr => [[-9, 9], [-7, 7] and [-2, 2]]
```

after all combinations of two elements have been enumerated.  Next combinations of three are considered, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward recursive solution for zero sum:

```
def find_subsets(arr)
  return arr if arr.empty?
  result = (0...arr.length).flat_map do |i|
     find_subsets(arr[0...i] + arr[i+1..-1])
  end
  result << arr if arr.inject(:+) == 0
  result.uniq
end
```

It collects all the results from dropping a single element from the array (this is the recursion), and adds to it the array itself, if it fits the requirement (sums to zero).

It is not the most efficient solution since it may repeat the calculation for subarrays coming from several paths (that it why the last line `uniq`s the result) - but it is the easiest implementation.